# How to save user profile model with image field and user field as OneToOneField variable in django rest framework

Tags: mysql, django, django-rest-framework

User model is as follow.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField('First Name', max_length=255, blank=True,
                                  null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField('Last Name', max_length=255, blank=True,
                                 null=False)
    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
```

User Profile model is as follow.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=avatar_image, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense. Note that django uses the `PIL` library to handle images

In your virtualenv
`pip install pillow`
In your `models.py`

```
from PIL import images
```

Images are handled as static files. Handling static files is described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/)